# what is the difference between dataform webpart and normal list webpart in sharepoint server?

Tags: sharepoint-2007

We can directly create a list in sharepoint UI (not sharepoint designer) or we can convert this list webpart into a datafrom webpart using sharepoint designer.What difference does it makes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you convert it into dataform webpart, the rendering mode is converted to XSLT. This XSLT can be edited in sharepoint designer or webpart properties itself to change the rendering of items.

Moreover, the type of webpart is changed from `ListViewWebPart` to `DataFormWebPart`.

The benefit of having rendering control , comes with some disadvantages. For ex, functionalities of ListViewWebPart like sorting, filtering, export to excel are unavailable/limited in functionality because of XSL limitations.

Comment: @@Madhur...Thank u...but i was wondering if these were the only differences!!! Are there no more differences?

Comment: Granularly, there will be much more differences since the type of webpart itself is changed. What exactly you are looking for ?

Comment: I mean the only reason we need the listviewwebpart to be converted to dataformwebpart is to work on in with Sharepoint Designer?

Comment: Its much more than that, the source of DataFormWebPArt can be modified to take parameters from QueryString, webpart connections. Moreover, the source itself can be changed from List to WebService, joins of list etc. DataForm WebPart is powerful webpart to display XML transformed data from any source, List is just one of its source.

Comment: @@Madhur, that was good.I really appreciate your help.Good night